# Replace a repeated code pattern by a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace the repeated code pattern here by a function:

```
june_hours = 243
june_cost = june_hours * 0.65
print("In June we spent: " + str(june_cost))

july_hours = 325
july_cost = july_hours * 0.65
print("In July we spent: " + str(july_cost))

august_hours = 298
august_cost = august_hours * 0.65
print("In August we spent: " + str(august_cost))
```

I tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
def print_monthly_expense(month, hours):
  cost = hours*0.65

print_monthly_expense(june, 243)
print_monthly_expense(july, 325)
print_monthly_expense(august, 298)

print("in" +  month + "we spent: " + str(cost))
```

Comment: You haven't posted a question, merely an assignment or task.
Please post the code that's giving you the problem: your attempt to generalize this into a function.  If you have no code, then it appears that you need a tutorial on functions -- or a local tutor -- rather than Stack Overflow.  This is not a tutorial site nor a coding service, so we're not sure what you expect from us.

Answer (score 0):

Here: First of all, you define a function with the `hours` and `cost` as arguments, then, you just return the `hour * cost` expression.
Example:

```
#costperhour(Hours, Cost)
def costperhour(hours, cost):
    return hours * cost


#Print june hours cost
print(f'In june we spent: {costperhour(243, 0.65)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code that "didn't work", you need to understand a bit more of how python works. Your issues here stems from two main things that I see.

1. The month names you use here are being interpreted as variable names, meaning that they are being used as references to values, instead of being used as values themselves. To use them as values, you would need to use quotes around the month names: `"june"`, `"july"`, etc.
2. The idea of variable scopes can be tricky at first, but basically, an unattached variable (like your `cost`) inside a function won't really have the same value outside of the function without a bit more effort. This means that the `cost` you are changing inside the function isn't actually causing any effect outside of the function. You would need to either `return` the value or do the `print` directly inside the function.

One possible resolution to the two issues would look like this:

```
def print_monthly_expense(month, hours):
    cost = hours*0.65
    print("in" + month + " we spent: " + str(cost))

print_monthly_expense("june", 243)
print_monthly_expense("july", 325)
print_monthly_expense("august", 298)
```

This approach is flawed for several reasons (the biggest of which is the mixing of the calculations and display of the results), but it should help you understand a bit more of what went wrong here.